# What's the significance of System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames in Attachment class?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
string fileName = "C:\Test\Sample.pdf";
Attachment attach = new Attachment(fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.pdf);
msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

v.s.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
string fileName = "C:\Test\Sample.pdf";
Attachment attach = new Attachment(fileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

What's the significance of adding the MIME type? Are there any pitfalls/drawbacks if I don't specify one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MIME type allows a recipient piece of software to readily identify the use and semantic nature of the file. They're related, but not tied, to file extensions, e.g. a MIME type of `application/octet-stream` can be associated with any number of file extensions.

It's generally advisable to include one whenever you transfer files, as it allows the program on the other end to work out how to properly display the content.

Not including it isn't the end of the world, it might just not open in the right program or be displayed properly on the other end, depending on how well attachments are managed by the mail client on the other end.

Comment: I see. Would that mean I have to explicitly check the file type that I'm attaching? For example, a user attaches an xml but I have indicated the MIME as a pdf. Would that case an issue?

Comment: Potentially, again it depends on how it gets handled at the other end, but again worst case is that is doesn't open correctly in preview etc. It definitely becomes an issue of validation in any case.

A package I've used in the past is [MimeTypeTap](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap) that handles calculating the MIME type for me. A solution like that might prove useful to prevent you doing it yourself.